# Why does Iron Man/Tony Stark name his suits as "Mark 1, Mark 2, Mark 3"?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man

In the movie **Iron Man**, why does Iron Man name his suits as **"Mark 1, Mark 2, Mark 3"** and so on. How did he came up with that naming pattern?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

"Mark" used in this way isn't a name; it's a synonym for "model" or "version".  According to [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mark), the relevant definition is

> A particular design or make of an item (now usually with following numeral). [from 15th c.]

A famous usage of this nomenclature was in the naming of the [Colossus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossus_computer) Mark I and Mark II computers, used in code-breaking during World War II.

Comment: Also, Ford Lincoln Mark III, Mark IV, Mark V ... And similarly, Jaguar S-Type, X-Type ...

Answer (score 1):

Mark means model or version. It was used for the arsenal of British tanks, the first one being mark 1.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Your help is appreciated, but this question already has an accepted answer (with essentially the same answer that you posted).